# Java Generics & Set of Sets

Tags: java, generics, containers

I'm a Java noob with a bit of C++ experience and I'm trying to create a Set of Sets in Java along the following lines (similar to what one would do in C++):

```
Set< Set< String > > collection = new TreeSet< Set< String > >();
Set< String > entry =  new TreeSet< String >();
collection.add( entry );
```

This builds fine, but then when the program is executed, a `java.util.TreeSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` exception is thrown.

Without reimplementing the wheel, how can one have a Set of Sets in Java?

Also, what is the deal with Java allowing broken code (e.g., the type mismatch) to compile?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I'd use HashSet in this particular case (see biziclop explanation for your issue).

Comment: Do you need your outer set to be a sorted set? If so, what would be the sorting rule?

Comment: Order does not matter; I used TreeSet just to illustrate my problem. My guess is that a HashSet will do as well (although I'm usually wary of any algorithm that relies on heuristics(i.e., the hash function) when I don't know enough about the data processed)

Comment: @Meh You can always provide your own `hashCode()` implementation and using unknown heuristics is still better than trying to use `TreeSet` for something it wasn't designed for. If you feel uneasy about `HashSet`, you can always read its source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the contract of [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), the requirement is laid out that all entries have to be `Comparable` or you have to provide a `Comparator`. (This is also why you didn't see a compile-time error: entries are only cast to `Comparable` in the absence of an explicit `Comparator`.)

It's got nothing to do with generics, it comes from the implementation of `TreeSet` itself: as it's a binary tree, it only makes sense if the entries can be ordered somehow.

If you tell a bit more about your specific problem, we can probably help you find the exact data structure you need but in general, if you don't care about the order of elements in a set, a `HashSet` is used. And again, in general, a `Set` of `Set`s is often a sign of sloppy design.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll probably implement a custom Comparator.

Comment: The specific problem is actually just as simple as the sample problem posted above. I need to keep track of unique sets of string tokens and then print them out. So it is a very simple problem and writing all sorts of wrapper classes would have been overdoing it, in my opinion. As for the design, well, I still like to have the option to shoot myself it the foot once in a while :)

Comment: @Meh Then your case is in the 1% when using a set of sets is justified. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an object to a `TreeSet` collection, that object's type must implement the `Comparable` interface, which `TreeSet` itself does not. Alternatively, you can provide a `Comparator` by creating the TreeSet with a different constructor.

It doesn't really make sense to use a `TreeSet` for this particular scenario because this is by definition an ordered collection and you don't seem to need an ordering of elements. You could try a `HashSet` instead.

Furthermore, to answer your second question, this error only appears at runtime because you are exploiting polymorphic behavior i.e. you are adding to a `Set`, which actually at runtime is bound to a `TreeSet`. This information is not known at compile time.

Comment: This isn't 100% correct as you can also provide an explicit comparator.

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks, I've added that information for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `TreeSet` is not completely "type-safe" from a generics perspective, because of its need to be able to accept either a custom comparator *or* use the natural ordering.

If `TreeSet` only used the natural ordering, it could be declared as `TreeSet<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` and it would be type-safe -- types which are not comparable to themselves simply could not be used as the parameter. On the other hand, if it always used a comparator, it would also be type-safe.

But the way it is designed right now allows you to create a `TreeSet` with no comparator (thus use the natural ordering) with an element type that is not comparable to itself. There is no compile-time check to enforce this. The failure is only noticed at runtime.

There is actually a way that `TreeSet` can be fixed. It can support both the natural ordering and custom comparator and be type-safe:

- Have a constructor that accepts a custom comparator
- Have no constructor for the natural ordering case. Instead, have a factory method to create a `TreeSet` that uses a natural ordering. The factory method can have a generics type bound `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` that requires the type to be comparable to itself

I don't know why the Java library designers didn't do it this way.